# Linear Algebra Expression Simplifying

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two images propagates through time $x_t,x_{t+1}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. I want to model each future pixel (i.e., $x_{t+1}^{ij}$) as a linear combination of all pixels from the previous state:

$$x_{t+1}^{ij} = trace(W^{ij}x_t) = \sum_{i'j'}W^{ij}_{i'j'}x_t^{i'j'},W^{ij}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$$

I struggle how to find a simple linear algebra expression such that

$$\vec{x_{t+1}} = W\vec{x_t}, W = [W^{11},\dots,W^{1m};\dots;W^{n1},\dots,W^{nm}],\text{ ';' is the start of a new column, }W\in\mathbb{R}^{nm\times nm},\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{nm}$$

$\vec{x}$ is the flattened image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you mean $\vec x = \operatorname{vec}(x)$, where vec denotes the row-major [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). Note that Matlab defaults to column-major vectorization, whereas Python defaults to row-major vectorization.

Let $\langle X,Y \rangle$ denote the Frobenius inner product of the matrices $X$ and $Y$. We can write
$$
x_{t+1}^{ij} = \langle (W^{ij})^T, x_t \rangle = \operatorname{vec}[(W^{ij})^T]^T \operatorname{vec}(x_t)
$$
Now, the entries of (the column-vector) $\operatorname{vec}(x_{t+1})$ appear in the order
$$
x_{t+1}^{1,1},x_{t+1}^{1,2}, \dots , x_{t+1}^{1,m}, x_{t+1}^{2,1},\dots,x_{t+1}^{n,m}
$$
Thus, we should have
$$
\vec x_{t+1} = \overbrace{\pmatrix{
\operatorname{vec}[(W^{11})^T]^T\\
\operatorname{vec}[(W^{12})^T]^T\\
\vdots\\
\operatorname{vec}[(W^{n,m})^T]^T
}}^W \vec x_{t}.
$$
Note that $\operatorname{vec}[(W^{ij})^T]^T$ is the column-major vectorization of $W^{ij}$.